# Django - Data is not submitted to my database, but no error

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

i'm making a system that tracks the owners of different phone companies, by letting a user add the owners' names. i'd like for the user to be able to add several owners at one time, and, hoping to avoid a lot of RegEx, Ajax and Node, i made 5 'Owner' tables in my database (the epitome of spaghetti code, i know). The last 4 Owner tables have null=True and blank=True, so that they are optional. When displaying this in the UI, i put each form field representation of the Owners in its own div and hide the last 4 divs. the user can choose to 'add another owner' by clicking a button, up to 4 extra owners. Rarely all five divs are filled out, so some of them always remain hidden by basic javascript. I then proceed to save all of them using .save() like any other model. when the user has filled out all the desired fields and hit "submit", everything runs fine, however... the data never gets sent to the database.

i get no errors anywhere, which leads me to guesstimate that the form i'm passing in when i save the data isn't valid. I know it's the 'several hidden forms' part that is the problem, because my system worked perfectly when i had only 1 owner table and nothing was hidden. however, since it doesn't give me any error messages, i'm at a loss to what i can do now - i have no idea why it doesn't think my form is valid.

note: i realize the django way is making formsets to add several instances of one table, but making these dynamic and hiding, say, 4 of 5 forms in the formset and displaying the rest on a button click, or true dynamic form behavior with loops, is very challenging and i don't have the javascript/react knowledge to do this. The ability to hide a form and show it on user's request is important - i know it could be solved easily otherwise by just using a formset and not hiding anything.

edit:
i've tried a few things to fix it, such as adding .instance between the form name and .save(), setting instance = (the form whose instances i'm editing) and then commit=False, and setting commit=True at the save at the end. the new 'instance' variable i make greys out witht he message "local variable 'instance' value not used.

i found an error in my models.py file: in PhoneCompany, owner_Set was supposed to be a ForeignKey, but was actually written as a ManyToManyField. when i corrected it, it returned the following error:  django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__phoneBook_companyinformation.owner_set_id
which is unsurprising, i guess; since data is never saved to the database, no owner set is made, and so, there is no owner set to refer to.

my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


Owner1(models.Model):
    owner1_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Owner2(models.Model):
    owner2_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Owner3(models.Model):
    owner3_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Owner4(models.Model):
    owner4_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Owner5(models.Model):
    owner5_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

OwnerSet(models.Model):
    owner1 = models.ForeignKey(Owner1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    owner2 = models.ForeignKey(Owner2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    owner3 = models.ForeignKey(Owner3, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    owner4 = models.ForeignKey(Owner4, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    owner5 = models.ForeignKey(Owner5, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

PhoneCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, default=None)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 400, default=None)
    owner_set = models.ForeignKey(OwnerSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

my forms.py file:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import *


class Form1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner1
        fields = ['owner1_name']

        widgets = {
            'owner1_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'owner1'})}


class Form2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner2
        fields = ['owner2_name']

        widgets = {
            'owner2_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'owner2'})}


class Form3(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner3
        fields = ['owner3_name']

        widgets = {
            'owner3_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'owner3'})}


class Form4(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner4
        fields = ['owner4_name']

        widgets = {
            'owner4_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'owner4'})}


class Form5(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner5
        fields = ['owner5_name']

        widgets = {
            'owner5_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'owner5'})}


class Form6(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OwnerSet
        fields = ['owner1_name']  
        # because i needed at least one to make the code run and it didn't like like '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'owner1_name': iTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'fk_owner1'})}


class Form7(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneCompany
        fields = ['name', 'address']

        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'comp_name'})
            'address': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'adrs'})
        }
```

my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import *

def company_input(request):
    form1 = Form1()  
    form2 = Form2() 
    form3 = Form3()  
    form4 = Form4()  
    form5 = Form5()  
    form6 = Form6() 
    form7 = Form7()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_owner1 = Form1(request.POST)
        form_owner2 = Form2(request.POST)
        form_owner3 = Form3(request.POST)
        form_owner4 = Form4(request.POST)
        form_owner5 = Form5(request.POST)
        form_ownerset = Form6(request.POST)
        form_company = Form7(request.POST)

        if form_owner1.is_valid() and form_owner2.is_valid() and 
        form_owner3.is_valid() and form_owner4.is_valid() and 
        form_owner5.is_valid() and form_ownerset.is_valid() and 
        form_company.is_valid():
            owner1 = form_owner1.save()
            owner2 = form_owner2.save()
            owner3 = form_owner3.save()
            owner4 = form_owner4.save()
            owner5 = form_owner5.save()

            instance = form_ownerset.save(commit=False) # greys out
            instance.owner1 = owner1
            instance.owner2 = owner2
            instance.owner3 = owner3
            instance.owner4 = owner4
            instance.owner5 = owner5
            ownerset = instance.save(commit=True)

            instance = form_company.save(commit=False)  # greys out
            instance.ownerset = ownerset
            company = instance.save()
        else: 
            print("Error: a form is not valid.")  # never returns the error...

    context = {'from1': form1,
               'form2': form2,
               'form3': form3,
               'form4': form4,
               'form5': form5,
               'form6': form6,
               'form7': form7,
               }
    return render(request, 'phoneBook/reg_owners.html', context)
```

my reg_owners.html file:

```
            <div id="owners" class="column">
                <div id="owner1">
                    <h5>Owner 1:</h5>
                    <br>
                    {{ form1.as_p }}
                </div>

                <div id="masterdiv">
                    <button id="btn1" style="width: 90px; margin-left: 40px" >Add Owner</button>
                    <div id="own2" style="display: none; margin-left: 40px; border-radius: 6px;">
                        <p>{{ form2.as_p }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <button id="btn2" style="margin-left: 40px; display: none">Add Owner</button>
                    <div id="own3" style="display: none; margin-left: 40px; border-radius: 6px;">
                        <p>{{ form3.as_p }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <button id="btn3" style="margin-left: 40px; display: none">Add Owner</button>
                    <div id="own4" style="display: none; margin-left: 40px; border-radius: 6px;">
                        <p>{{ form4.as_p }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <button id="btn4" style="margin-left: 40px; display: none">Add Owner</button>
                    <div id="own5" style="display: none; margin-left: 40px; border-radius: 6px;">
                        <p>{{ form5.as_p }}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

my add_owner.js file:

```
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2")
const btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3")
const btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4")

# own1 is not included, because the first owner form is required and never changes or hides
const own2 = document.getElementById("own2")
const own3 = document.getElementById("own3")
const own4 = document.getElementById("own4")
const own5 = document.getElementById("own5")

btn1.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(btn1.innerHTML === "Add Owner"){
        btn1.innerHTML = "Remove";
        if(btn2.style.display === "none" && own2.style.display === "none"){
            btn2.style.display = "block";
            own2.style.display = "block";
        }
        else if (btn2.style.display === "block" && own2.style.display === "block"){
            btn2.style.display = "none";
            own2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    /*close the div*/
    else{
        btn1.innerHTML = "Add Owner"
        if(own2.style.display === "block" && btn2.style.display === "block"){
            own2.style.display = "none"
            btn2.style.display = "none"
        }
    }

}

btn2.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(btn2.innerHTML === "Add Owner"){
        btn2.innerHTML = "Remove";
        btn1.disabled = true
        /*Display button 3 and owner 3*/
        if(btn3.style.display === "none" && own3.style.display === "none"){
            btn3.style.display = "block";
            own3.style.display = "block";
        }  /*hide button 3 and owner 3*/
        else if (btn3.style.display === "block" && own3.style.display === "block"){
            btn3.style.display = "none";
            own3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    /*close the div*/
    else{
        btn2.innerHTML = "Add Owner"
        if(own3.style.display === "block" && btn3.style.display === "block"){
            own3.style.display = "none"
            btn3.style.display = "none"
            btn1.disabled = false
        }
    }
}

btn3.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(btn3.innerHTML === "Add Owner"){
        btn3.innerHTML = "Remove";
        btn2.disabled = true
        /*Display button 3 and owner 3*/
        if(btn4.style.display === "none" && own4.style.display === "none"){
            btn4.style.display = "block";
            own4.style.display = "block";
        }  /*hide button 3 and owner 3*/
        else if (btn4.style.display === "block" && own4.style.display === "block"){
            btn4.style.display = "none";
            own4.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    /*close the div*/
    else{
        btn3.innerHTML = "Add Owner"
        if(own4.style.display === "block" && btn4.style.display === "block"){
            own4.style.display = "none"
            btn4.style.display = "none"
            btn2.disabled = false
        }
    }
}


btn4.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(btn4.innerHTML === "Add Owner"){
        btn4.innerHTML = "Remove";
        btn3.disabled = true
        if(own5.style.display === "none"){
            own5.style.display = "block";
        }  /*hide button 3 and author 3*/
        else if (own5.style.display === "block"){
            own5.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    /*close the div*/
    else{
        btn4.innerHTML = "Add iOwner"
        if(own5.style.display === "block"){
            own5.style.display = "none"
            btn3.disabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `save` on `form_ownerset.instance` since you changed `instance`. So `form_ownerset.instance.save()`

Comment: i tried both your suggestions, and they didn't make any difference

Comment: Can you also try the same with `form_company`?

Comment: yes. although it doesn't look like the instance = trick will ever work - it just greys out and says "local variable 'instance' value is not used"

Comment: i've added form_(x).instance.save() under everywhere i change an instance now, and no difference

Comment: Can you update the question with your current attempts?

Comment: the question is updated :)

Comment: Ah it grays out because you are using `form_ownerset.instance` instead of `instance`. Try to check and copy the exact code I shared

Comment: I updated my answer to an exact snippet you can try

Comment: ahh sorry, i guess ir ead that too fast. i did it right this time, and still no difference

Comment: Even for company right? I added that in my answer. And to confirm, nothing at all in the db?

Comment: for company too yes, and no database change at all. i'm noticing that the redirect is faster than usual - prob because data isn't being passed in

Comment: And no errors  printer? Weird...

Comment: yup, no errors. it's really weird :/

Comment: Last one, can you confirm it gets through as a POST request?

Comment: uuhh, how do i do that?

Comment: Maybe print in your view that it gets in the if statement as a post request

Comment: still not sure how to do that.. this is my 2nd week using Django and developing a system so i'm not too versed in, wlel, most things hah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235403/discussion-between-bdbd-and-sunny-garden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my OwnerSet functionality. in forms.py, i defined that i wanted owner1_id to be a field, but i never actually passed any data into the field or really used it at all. this threw a validationError in the command terminal whenever i tried submitting data, which wiped the POST request and so, there was no data to send to the database. Removing the OwnerSet form in forms.py and routing all of the owner_ids to company in views.py fixed the issue and once again, data is being submitted to my database.

Answer (score 0):

```
            form_ownerset.instance.owner1 = owner1
            form_ownerset.instance.owner2 = owner2
            form_ownerset.instance.owner3 = owner3
            form_ownerset.instance.owner4 = owner4
            form_ownerset.instance.owner5 = owner5
```

After all the above, call:

```
            form_ownerset.instance.save()
```

If it still doesn't work, try to save the form first without comitting to get the instance, and then edit, and save:

```
            instance = form_ownerset.save(commit=False)
            instance.owner2 = owner2
            instance.owner3 = owner3
            instance.owner4 = owner4
            instance.owner5 = owner5
            instance.save()
```

Or to make it clearer:

```
            ownerset = form_ownerset.save(commit=False)
            ownerset.owner1 = owner1
            ownerset.owner2 = owner2
            ownerset.owner3 = owner3
            ownerset.owner4 = owner4
            ownerset.owner5 = owner5
            ownerset.save()

            company = form_company.save(commit=False)
            company.ownerset = ownerset
            company.save()
```